# Javafx SSL client configuration to consume my Spring boot ssl secured Rest Api

Tags: java, spring, apache, ssl, javafx

I developped a secured Spring boot Rest Api using basic auth header, now I m trying to add SSL to secure against Man In The Middle attack as the spring tutorial suggest so [I activated the SSL security on my spring by generating a keystore.JKS that I Added to the ressources. server works fine .](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-boot/spring-boot-ssl-https-example/)

Now I have a JavaFX Client where I use the Unirest Api to do My requests but I dont know how to update my client to successfully do a get/post request to my server.

I tried so much tutorials but none works I don't want to disable ssl

Here is my spring boot configuration :

```
 # The format used for the keystore 
 server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
 # The path to the keystore containing the certificate
 server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
 # The password used to generate the certificate
 server.ssl.key-store-password=mypass
 # The alias mapped to the certificate
 server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
```

My server is starting well using postman is fine when I do accept the certeficate in chrome.

for my java client I m using this snippet :

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

private static Stage parent;
private static Parent root;

 static
    {
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","c:/ssl/keystore.jks");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "mypass");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "c:/ssl/keystore.jks");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "mypass");
   }

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {


      Unirest.setHttpClient(HttpClients.createSystem());

    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));
    parent = stage;
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
//        stage.setOpacity(0.2);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
```

as you see I m trying to config my Unirest httpClient in the application launching

```
  HttpResponse<String> asJson = Unirest.get("http://localhost:8181/logins/login/?us_username=" + username.getText() + "&us_pwdusr=" +  Crypto.getSha(password.getText()))
                    .header("authorization", "Basic " + value)
                    .header("cache-control", "no-cache").asString();
```

but when I do a get methode over my server (I have a redirect in the server from 8181 and 8080 to 8443 activated) I m getting the following error

> Caused by: com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for 
>   doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []    at
>   com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:143)
>     at
>   com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asString(BaseRequest.java:56)
>     at
>   easypos.easyposclientfx.FXMLController.login(FXMLController.java:130)
>     ... 59 more
>
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException:
>   Certificate for  doesn't match any of the subject
>   alternative names: []     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:467)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
>     at
>   com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:138)
>     ... 61 more

trying to read this I do understand that my certeficate alias or name is maybe all my certeficate is not registred in the system

in response to this idea I did added the certeficate to cacerts in the java jre environement but still the same error

What should I do to fix this?

Here is the certeficate as suggested

[image: my certaficate that I downloaded using chrome]

Comment: I will update my login methode to post as csrf spring boot security mention over ssl so plz overlook it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception you are having suggests below:

Your client system's java keystore (JRE which is being used by client application) is asking for a certificate from service provider and when it receives it, it is not able to match the subject alternative name of the server with it.

Example : You are calling your webservice like http://localhost:8181/logins/login

But the certificate that is installed on your REST producer service has a Subject name like "abc.com" which creates a mismatch between localhost and abc.com comparison, hence, throwing the error.

In order to test the services and client interaction locally, you can use any of below techniques:

- create a new certificate with subject name as localhost and use this
  certificate in client keystore as well as in rest producer
- Install Apache HTTP server locally, enable mod_ssl module to enable
  https. Once done spoof your DNS by making a host entry in host file
  with your hostname and IP address as 127.0.0.1

Can you share the self-signed certificate's screenshot like the one in image below:

[image: Stack Overflow Certificate]

It will help the community explore more options to help you better.

Comment: your right but what should I do now should  I creat another certificate ?? using localhost ? what if I host my sb rest into heruko should I reuse another certeficate ?

Comment: Yes, for local testing purpose, you can do any of below:

- create a new certificate with subject name as localhost and use this certificate in client keystore as well as in rest producer
- Install Apache HTTP server locally, enable mod_ssl module to enable https. Once done spoof your DNS by making a host entry in host file with your hostname and IP address as 127.0.0.1

Pardon the formatting as replying from phone.

Comment: please update your comment as an answer so I can accept it and it could be relevant to other people

Comment: Sure @MohammedHousseynTaleb - I have updated the steps to test locally in my original answer.